# Iptables - allow "reply" traffic

Tags: iptables

In iptables I drop all incoming traffic. But I want e.g. PING to work when sent to the blocked addresses.

What works is if I allow ESTABLISHED. But this also allows existing (=established) connections to continue even if the iptables rules say they should be blocked/dropped.

In *[man iptables](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables)*:

> **ESTABLISHED** meaning that the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions

I don't see any better state to identify connection which just received first packet in the second direction - first reply to an outgoing request.

Is there a way to set rules for these "newly established" connections?

Maybe **NEW** could be somehow used on the outgoing connection to allow incoming packets on it?

---

**UPDATE:** Since i can't express the intent otherwise:

I wish to implement a whitelist, so a few specific addresses should be able to connect, others should be dropped. So i have:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

But this also blocks reply traffic, so if this computer sends a ping to the whitelisted addresses, it **will not receive a reply**.
That is why i added the ESTABLISHED rule, which fixes that problem:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But this introduces another problem: if a connection existed before applying these rules from a non-whitelisted addresss 9.9.9.9, **it will be allowed to continue**.

How can I allow reply traffic without allowing existing connection that should be blocked by the iptables rules?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with "But this also allows connections to persist even when they should be blocked."?

Comment: @MathiasWeidner I mean that after setting a rule, say block 1.2.3.4, if a TCP connection was open at that time the ESTABLISHED flag will let it continue living. The ESTABLISHED flag is too permissive for me, but i don't see a functional alternative.

Comment: IPTABLES rules are applied by reading the file from top to bottom and the first rule that applies is used. E.g. if you put ESTABLISHED at the end of the rule set AFTER you drop or block, the ESTABLISHED rule won't apply. Ideally you set your firewall to POLICY DROP, open the ports for just what you need and in the end allow ESTABLISHED and RELATED. Only a connection that was established via a NEW rule falls into these categories. TL;DR: The order of your rules matters.

Comment: @Broco i do have INPUT POLICY DROP, but it also blocks traffic that is a reply to an outgoing request. Established allows it, but also allows other unwanted traffic. I added an example to the question.

Comment: Established doesn't allow unwanted traffic. But you could add a destination address to your ESTABLISHED rule instead of allowing it for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, your problem arises when your firewall rules where to permissive and you add a rule to block traffic that was allowed before. Then the traffic that was already allowed and has an open connection in the conntrack module is allowed after the new rule is in place.

You should have a look at the [conntrack-tools](http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/conntrack.html).

Using the `conntrack` program you would list the active connections and explicitely delete the unwanted connections.

Please be aware that ESTABLISHED within the conntrack module refers to the state of the connections known to the conntrack module. That means, after you have deleted the connection from there, the iptables rules will prevent the connection from being established anew because the next datagramm would set the state to NEW.

Comment: The problem is i have to set the permisive rule or other stuff breaks. I am asking if iptables have a better way to set it up. I added the specific example to the question if that helps.

Comment: hows about established,related

Comment: @djdomi what do you mean? The question was about ESTABLISHED.

Comment: instead only `--state ESTABLISHED` he may can use `--state ESTABLISHED,RELATED` which should it restrict once more because it will check for it

Comment: @djdomi RELATED is about traffic that does not belong to a connection which is already registered by the conntrack module but is related to it. For instance a data connection in an FTP session or an ICMP message regarding a registered IP connection. Of course I would put it together with ESTABLISHED in an iptables rule, but it doesn't have to do with the original question.

Comment: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j accept` 
and `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j accept` may give a option to accept echo request if i understand